# Can't restructure multidimentional array as one?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have header `field` array and user `info` array ,so I need to re-arrange new one multi array.I want to set the `field` array values to `new key`.Move `info` index of 0 to under Name,1 to Age,2 to Gender...

```
var customer = [];

var field = ["Name","Age","Gender"];

var info = [
 ["David","32","Male"],
 ["John","35","Male"],
 ["Enna","28","Female"],
 ["Watson","22","Female"]
 ];

info.map(function(each,i){
each.map(function(data,index){
  customer[field[index]] = data;
});
});

console.log(customer);//[Name: "Watson", Age: "22", Gender: "Female"]
```

But,I just get array is just one like above console.log

How to output like this ,i have no idea

```
// ["Name"] :["David","John","Enna","Watson"]
// ["Age"] :["32"],["35"],["28"],["22"]
// ["Gender"] :["Male"],["Male"],["Female"],["Female"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer you are looking for

```
    var customer = {};

var field = ["Name","Age","Gender"];

var info = [
 ["David","32","Male"],
 ["John","35","Male"],
 ["Enna","28","Female"],
 ["Watson","22","Female"]
 ];

info.map(function(each,i){
    each.map(function(data,index){
        if (!customer[field[index]])customer[field[index]] = []
        customer[field[index]].push(data);
    });
});
console.log(customer);

//sample output  
{ Name: [ 'David', 'John', 'Enna', 'Watson' ],
  Age: [ '32', '35', '28', '22' ],
  Gender: [ 'Male', 'Male', 'Female', 'Female' ] }
```

Comment: then change it to `var customer = {}` BTW earlier also worked for me

Comment: you are right, it works with an array while an array is an objetct, but it is misleading.

Comment: @NinaScholz i have updated the answer to store result in object rather than array

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use for every array [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and as result an object with the field elements as properties.

- `customer` needs to be an object. (It works with an array as well, but it is missleading, while array is a special form of an object.)
- `customer` contains properties from `field` as array
- inner loop creates peoperties if not set
- the values are pushed to their corresponding array

```js
var field = ["Name", "Age", "Gender"],
    info = [
         ["David", "32", "Male"],
         ["John", "35", "Male"],
         ["Enna", "28", "Female"],
         ["Watson", "22", "Female"]
    ],
    customer = function (data, keys) {
        var r = {};
        data.forEach(function (a) {
            keys.forEach(function (k, i) {
                r[k] = r[k] || [];
                r[k].push(a[i]);
            });
        });
        return r;
    }(info, field);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(customer, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, I think. Does a such output match your expectations?

```
var field = ["Name", "Age", "Gender"];
var info = [
  ["David", "32", "Male"],
  ["John", "35", "Male"],
  ["Enna", "28", "Female"],
  ["Watson", "22", "Female"]
];

var customers = field.map(function(key, index) {
  var item = {};
  item[key] = info.map(function(dataItem) {
    return dataItem[index];
  });
  return item;
});
```